# JWT scheme with different signing algorithms

Tags: authentication, jwt

I'm planning to implement a (slightly non-standard?) JWT authentication scheme with refresh and access tokens, in which refresh and access tokens use different signing algorithms:

- refresh token uses HS256 and is only processed by The Main Application
- access tokens use ES256. The Main Application signs the access token with its private key, and that token can be later verified by The Microservice, which has The Main Application's public key. This is done so that The Microservice is not able to issue access tokens

Ignoring the less than ideal choice of ES256, is there any reason not to use this scheme?

Comment: I Guess it would good to understand why you’d do this?

Comment: @keithRozario to share authentication with the Microservice in a way that the Microservice is unable to create access tokens on its own.

Comment: the microservice will only ever have the Public Key of the 'Main' application -- hence it'll never be able to create access tokens either. Only the Main application with the private key would be able to issue access tokens, or refresh tokens.

Comment: As this is not following the OAuth2 standard I am trying to understand the purpose of this solution. The only purpose that comes to my mind is that you want to limit access to Microservices for only known client's (Main Apps). So this is something like authentication. Am I correct?